# How I can count how many repeated numbers in a file and then organize them by repetitions?

Tags: bash, awk, tr

I have a file that needs organized a number of repeats, my file has 6 rows and 3120 lines each member has 1 or 2 digits, total 18720 numbers with one or 2 digits.

I would like to count how many 1, how many 2, how many 3 so on to how many 45 I have in my file and output organanize most reported number to less repeated.
Example:

```
5   7   13  25  26  44
12  21  26  28  32  44
10  20  22  26  40  44
13  18  19  20  22  23
9   15  17  19  22  43
10  19  28  29  37  45
2   8   12  13  22  35
3   23  24  26  38  39
3   14  19  20  33  43
2   3   8   35  36  43
2   8   25  29  37  43
3   24  27  29  38  44
5   20  23  32  33  40
11  17  22  26  33  36
1   6   31  32  39  44
4   22  27  31  36  43
3   6   18  22  35  44
11  13  24  28  32  33
17  22  27  29  42  44
8   9   16  23  29  44
13  19  20  33  37  40
18  21  29  31  34  44
14  15  20  31  32  41
6   32  33  40  41  43
11  17  18  31  43  44
1   9   10  22  24  34
6   8   9   35  37  38
14  18  21  36  40  43
11  16  17  32  34  38
1   5   14  22  23  24
5   19  21  22  32  45
12  17  20  22  32  44
9   27  32  38  42  44
4   12  16  26  42  45
6   7   8   16  39  42
5   6   13  18  27  28
```

Output:

most repeted first with number of repetion

5=30 Five reapeted 30 times

4=28 Four reapeted 28 times

.........

.........

.........

35=0 Thirty five repeated 0 times

I try this but doesn't work and I'm not expert to change code

```
$ tr -s " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n r | awk '{print $2 " = " $1}'
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '{cnt[$0]++} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for (i in cnt) print i" = "cnt[i]}' file
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 " = " $1}'
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <nums | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2n | awk '{print $2 " = " $1}'
$ awk -v RS=" +|\n" '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)printf "%d = %d\n",x,a[x]}' file
$ awk -v RS=" +|\n" '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)printf "%d = %d\n",x,a[x]}' f|sort -nr -k3
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
tr -s ' ' <file.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -k1,1rn -k2,2rn | sed 's/^ \+//; s/ /=/'
```

- `tr -s ' '` will make successive spaces into one
- `tr ' ' '\n'` will convert spaces into newlines
- `sort -n` will do numeric `sort`-ing
- `uniq -c` will do the count
- `sort -k1,1rn -k2,2rn | sed 's/^ \+//; s/ /=/'` will format the output the way you want.

**Example:**

```
$ tr -s ' ' <file.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -k1,1rn -k2,2rn | sed 's/^ \+//; s/ /=/'
12=44
12=22
10=32
8=43
7=20
6=33
6=29
6=26
6=19
6=18
6=17
6=13
6=8
6=6
5=40
5=38
5=31
5=27
5=24
5=23
5=9
5=5
5=3
4=42
4=37
4=36
4=35
4=28
4=21
4=16
4=14
4=12
4=11
3=45
3=39
3=34
3=10
3=2
3=1
2=41
2=25
2=15
2=7
2=4
```

Comment: If we can add locale, and subtract several punctuation marks, etc. (anything else, e.g. to replace "numeric" sorting?) we can perhaps turn this into a handy (nautilus) script to create word lists of text files. Some help would be much appreciated ;-)

Comment: @Sadi Yes..surely can be done..removing non alphanumerics is easy, you can use `tr -d [:alnum:]`, then the process is somewhat similar..

Comment: Thanks, but I guess there's a typo here as this would delete all alphanumerical characters, if I'm not mistaken. However, I've found that adding `tr -d [:punct:]` and `tr -d [:digit:]` goes a long way to this end, except that at the beginning of the output list I'm getting a line displaying highest repetition number for "an invisible character".

Comment: @Sadi Oops..my bad..I meant `tr -cd [:alnum:]`

Comment: Unfortunately this made things worse, deleting all non-ASCII characters (including spaces and line breaks) and resulting in just one line. In this case the solution I've found seems better, and it might be perfect when I can get rid of that blank entry at the top of the list.

Comment: @Sadi No problem.. for me it's like shooting blindly..I think you should make your own to suite your need :)

Answer (score 6):

This produces the a count of the number of occurrences of a number, sorted in descending order by number of occurrences:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++;} END{for (i in a)print i"="a[i]}' file | sort -rnt= -k2,2
44=12
22=12
32=10
43=8
20=7
8=6
6=6
33=6
29=6
26=6
19=6
18=6
17=6
13=6
[...snip...]
```

In the above, `44=12` means that `44` was repeated `12` times.

#### GNU awk

If you have GNU awk (gawk) installed, you can eliminate the need for a pipeline and do it all in one awk statement:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++;} END{for (i in a)print i"="a[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an AWK variation (I haven't AWK for a long time...)

```
awk -v RS="[ \n]+" '{a[$1]++} END{ for(b in a){print b,a[b] | "sort -rnk2,2"}}'
```